# Lower bound for the function $h(x)=(1+1/x)\log(1+x)-1$ for $x > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am reading a paper and in the paper, there is a result having no proof. I was wondering if anyone could give me a hint on this result. The result is the following:
$$
h(x)\geq \begin{cases}
x/4, & \text{if } x\leq4;\\
(1/2)\log x, & \text{if } x\geq4,
\end{cases}
$$
where the function $h$ is defined for all $x > 0$ by
$$h(x)=(1+1/x)\log(1+x)-1.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you are requiring $x > 0$, as it's not true if $-1 < x < 0$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. x is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $0<x\leq 4$ we need to prove that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(1+x)-1\geq\frac{x}{4}$$ or $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=\ln(1+x)-\frac{4x+x^2}{4(1+x)}.$$
But, $$f'(x)=\frac{x(2-x)}{3(1+x)^2},$$
which says that $$\min_{0\leq x\leq4}f=\min\{f(0),f(4)\}=f(0)=0.$$
By the same way you can prove the second inequality:

after calculating of derivative use AM-GM.